# Eclipse : ScheduledExecutorService.scheduleWithFixedDelay does not remove on publish

Tags: java, eclipse

I got  weird problem.

I have a ScheduledExecutorService.scheduleWithFixedDelay which doesn't not "stop" when i click publish / stop-restart server .

When i republish, there will be 2 service running and the number of same service running depends on how many times I click publish.

This does not go away after I stop and start server.

I have to close eclipse and open to stop it and I notice this happen only after i edit the class that initialize the service.

I'm unable to paste the codes but is very simple.. just a Singleton and holds the service

```
private final ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = 
       Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);

scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
                public void run() { system.out("hello" }
            }, 60 * 60, SECONDS);
```

I can't seems to find out the issue, can someone help me please.

Comment: There must be something wrong with your deployment process. Stopping and starting the server MUST allways stop the services, unless your deployment process publishes the application multiple times everytime you click on publish. This can only be debugged when knowing your installation (internal/external start, tomcat/jboss).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're supposed to shut down the scheduler when the application is undeployed. The easier way to do that is to declare an implement a [ServletContextListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html), and shut down the schedler in the `contextDestroyed()` method.

Comment: yup, I did consider this but I don't see why I need to do that because personally I feel the API should be able to handle it.

Comment: Which API? How could the container be aware that you spawned threads?

Comment: I meant the ScheduledExecutorService... Is this the only solution? will the solution below work?

Comment: Same thing: The ScheduledExecutorService is a utility class that isn't connected at all to JEE and webapps. It doesn't know it's used in a webapp, and doesn't know when a webapp is destroyed. So, provide a thread factory which creates daemon threads, or shut down your service when the app is destroyed. Bote that the daemon thread will only stop running when the JVM exits. Not when the appis redeployed.

Comment: That means registering to the shutdown scheduler would be the best approach for my issue?

Comment: That means that I think shutting down the thread pool when it's not needed is the cleanest solution. Waiting for the JVM exit is not clean, especially in development, where you frequently redeploy the app.

Comment: one last question.. lets say I have a lot of scheduler created. is there a way to shut them all down...Currently I have to scheduler.shutdown() for each scheduler.

Comment: That's what you must do. But I would rather ask myself: is it normal to have many schedulers in a single app? Shouldn't on be sufficient?

Answer (score 1):

Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1); creates a non-daemon worker thread and it prevents JVM from shutting down unless you shutdown scheduler explicitly

```
scheduler.shutdown();
```

alternatevely, you can do the following

```
    ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1,
            new ThreadFactory() {
                public Thread newThread(Runnable r) {
                    Thread t = new Thread(r);
                    t.setDaemon(false);
                    return t;
                }

            });
```

in this case the worker thread will be a daemon and will not prevent the JVM from exiting when the program finishes

Comment: I like the set Daemon solution better but is there anything I should be aware? will the thread stop when I republish?